# Get cell size for GRASS raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis

How do you get the cell size of a GRASS raster in QGIS?
QGIS has properties, but no raster cell size.

Answer (score 6):

You just right click the layer and select Properties.

Then go the Metadata tab. Scroll down and look for "Pixel Size".

Answer (score 4):

You can use the GRASS tool named **r.info**. It'll give you a ascii table like below, where you can find the resolution ("Res") :

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Map:      tmp1506276680083               Date: Sun Sep 24 20:11:21 2017    |
 | Mapset:   PERMANENT                      Login of Creator: Gisnside        |
 | Location: temp_location                                                    |
 | DataBase: C:\Path\Local\Temp\processingeaf8118a1ee94                       |
 | Title:                                                                     |
 | Timestamp: none                                                            |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                                                            |
 |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0               |
 |   Data Type:    CELL                                                       |
 |   Rows:         728                                                        |
 |   Columns:      855                                                        |
 |   Total Cells:  622440                                                     |
 |        Projection: unnamed                                                 |
 |            N:        728    S:          0   Res:     1                     |
 |            E:        855    W:          0   Res:     1                     |
 |   Range of data:    min = 0  max = 255                                     |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Data Description:                                                        |
 |    gnr par r.external                                                      |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Comments:                                                                |
 |    r.external --overwrite -o input="C:\Path\myraster.jpg"                  |
 | output="tmp1506276680083" band=1                                           |
 |                                                                            |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with rasters that did not contain res information in their metadata. Just select the raster layer and click "Save As...". The "Save Raster Layer As" menu pops up, where the raster resolution (Dx,Dy) options are automatically populated and you can check the resolution from there.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem was that the raster that I was looking at was loaded from a GRASS database and did not offer pixel size in it's metadata. I then saved the raster onto disk, loaded it, and it did show pixel size.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by PyQIGS:

```
MNT = QgsRasterLayer(" your raster" )
provider = MNT.dataProvider()

## Width of the Cell
pixelWidth = MNT.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
## Heigh of the Cell
pixelHeight = MNT.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
```