# How to examine pixel size (degree or length) under different projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

In ArcGis, we can check x y size of each pixel in raster property. How to check in Qgis?

[image]

Comment: Do either of the answers on [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119229/get-cell-size-for-raster-in-qgis) thread work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-Click on the Raster image and go to the Metadata tab.  Then scroll down to properties and scroll within that text box until you see pixel size.  This gives you the X and Y dimensions.

[image]